# Auto cast subclass instance to interface

Tags: go

I have a interface, like this:

```golang
type Collections[T any] interface {
    Add(element T) bool

    Get(index uint64) T

    Length() uint64
}
```

and I have a subclass implement the interface:

```golang
type LinkedList[T any] struct {
    size uint64
    head *linkedListNode[T]
    tail *linkedListNode[T]
}
```

and I define a package function:

```golang
func IsEmpty[T any](collections Collections[T]) bool {
    if collections == nil {
        return true
    }

    return collections.Length() <= 0
}
```

now I have a question, if I have a constuctor like this:

```golang
func NewLinkedList[T any]() Collections[T] {
    linkList := &LinkedList[T]{size: 0}

    headNode := &linkedListNode[T]{}
    tailNode := &linkedListNode[T]{}

    headNode.next = tailNode
    tailNode.pre = headNode

    linkList.head = headNode
    linkList.tail = tailNode

    return linkList
}
```

then I can use the package function like this:

```golang
func TestLinkedListCreate(t *testing.T) {
    var obj = datastruct.NewLinkedList[string]()
    empty := datastruct.IsEmpty(obj)
    println(empty)
}
```

but if I have a constuctor like this:

```golang
func NewLinkedList[T any]() *LinkedList[T] {
    linkList := &LinkedList[T]{size: 0}

    headNode := &linkedListNode[T]{}
    tailNode := &linkedListNode[T]{}

    headNode.next = tailNode
    tailNode.pre = headNode

    linkList.head = headNode
    linkList.tail = tailNode

    return linkList
}
```

I have to use package function like this:

```golang
func TestLinkedListCreate(t *testing.T) {
    var obj datastruct.Collections[string] = datastruct.NewLinkedList[string]()
    empty := datastruct.IsEmpty(obj)
    println(empty)
}
```

so why golang can auto cast subclass to interface in function, but can't cast subclass to interface in declare?

I use golang 1.19

Comment: Go has no casts, no classes, no inheritance and no subclasses. Your question makes no sense. You cannot do traditional OOP in Go. Redesign

Comment: ok, I got this.

Answer (score 1):

[Volker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266756/volker) said [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73349010/auto-cast-subclass-instance-to-interface/73357814#comment129534867_73349010):

> Go has no casts, no classes, no inheritance and no subclasses. Your question makes no sense. You cannot do traditional OOP in Go. Redesign

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? If not, delete it.

Comment: I think it's like a tip, maybe should keep it